# How to access Managed Entities inside managed aks cluster on azure through terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, identity, azure-service-principal

I have setup a AKS cluster through terraform and in the same Resource group, I have create an Application gateway. As such

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name                              = var.aks_name
  tags                              = var.tags
  location                          = var.vnet_location
  resource_group_name               = local.aks_resource_group
  dns_prefix                        = "k8s"
  oidc_issuer_enabled               = true
  role_based_access_control_enabled = true
  azure_policy_enabled              = true
  #workload_identity_enabled         = true

  default_node_pool {
    name            = var.node_pool_name
    node_count      = var.node_count
    vm_size         = var.node_type
    os_disk_size_gb = var.os_disk_size_gb
    vnet_subnet_id  = local.aks_subnet_id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  ingress_application_gateway {
    gateway_id = var.application_gateway_id
  }
...
```

During creation, Azure creates a MC_******* resource group for the managed cluster and I use a service principal to deploy all Terraform resources
The ingress controller for the application "ingress_application_gateway" acquires automatically a managed entity deployed inside the MC_**** resource group.
I need to access that managed entity in order to set some needed access policies on dependent resources.

Ingress controller need access to both the application gateway aswell as the original Resource group, as such;

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Ingress controller running on AKS
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
data "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_resource_group" {
  name = local.aks_resource_group
}

#Gateway ingress controller should have reader access on resource group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "igc_reader_access" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_resource_group.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.ingress_controller_identity.principal_id
}

#Gateway ingress controller should have contributor access on application gateway
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ag_contributor_access" {
  scope                = var.application_gateway_id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.ingress_controller_identity.principal_id
}

data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "ingress_controller_identity" {
  name                = "ingressapplicationgateway-qa"
  resource_group_name = "MC_RG-Digital-Service-qa_westeurope"
}
```

To the question, how can I setup so my Service principal (that is used to create the azurerm_kubernetes_cluster resource) to have reader access on the MC_****** resource group created by azure for aks.

I dont want to give complete subscription contributor access to my Service Principal.

Answer (score 0):

You could do smtg like this, when your execute Terraform as the Service Principal (We could reduce the data resources if the Application Gateway would be in the same Terraform project):

```
# get current client ( your Service principal)
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

# get MC Resource Group
data "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_mc_rg" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.cluster]
  name = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.node_resource_group
}

# get Application Gateway
data "azurerm_application_gateway" "aks_igc" {
  name                = "existing-app-gateway"
  resource_group_name = "existing-resources"
}

# read Managed identity
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "ingress_controller_identity" {
  name                = "ingressapplicationgateway-qa"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_mc_rg.id
}

# assign reader to current client 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rg_aks_nodes_owners" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_mc_rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

#Gateway ingress controller should have reader access on resource group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "igc_reader_access" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.aks_mc_rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.ingress_controller_identity.principal_id
}

#Gateway ingress controller should have contributor access on application gateway
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ag_contributor_access" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_application_gateway.aks_igc.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.ingress_controller_identity.principal_id
}
```